# Spy: stub method call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, spy

I would like to stub `jasperreports` method call from the following class:

```
 public class JRPdfExporter extends JRAbstractExporter<PdfReportConfiguration, PdfExporterConfiguration, OutputStreamExporterOutput, JRPdfExporterContext> {
```

In my test I have:

```
JRExporter jrPdfExporter = spy(new JRPdfExporter());
doNothing().when(jrPdfExporter).exportReport();
```

But seems like my assumptions are ignored here. I still get NullPointerException during `exportReport()` method invocation.

How can we fix this?

---

**Edited:**

I the tested Class `Exporter` initializes as following:

```
protected JRExporter getPdfExporter()
{
    JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(
    // several params setting
    return exporter;
}
```

then it calls like this:

```
exporter.exportReport();
```

I tried to use PowerMockito but it doesn't help either:

```
JRPdfExporter jrPdfExporter = PowerMockito.mock(JRPdfExporter.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(JRPdfExporter.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(jrPdfExporter);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(jrPdfExporter).exportReport();
```

Comment: show us ur code, not only test class. How is exportReport method called and how is jrPdfExporter instantiated?

Comment: @pvpkiran, done

Comment: You cannot spy new object creation with mocktio, You need to use PowerMock. have a look into that

Comment: PowerMock doesn't help either

Comment: where is the getPdfExporter() method? In your class under test? It would be useful if you posted the full method you are trying to test.